# Is it possible to run Roblox on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, games, software-compatibility

The title says it all. I know it's an ARM system, but I just want to know if I can run it.

- Board: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2
- OS: Ubuntu Mate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Pi support is non existent.

**Problem 1**
They advertise that they can run on Android devices. This means that at some level there is support for the ARM processor, but my guess is that the Pi 3 is not powerful enough to run it well.

**Problem 2**
Linux is currently [not supported](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203312800-Computer-Hardware-Operating-System-Requirements).

Comment: What about using something like https://emteria.com to run the Android package on Raspberry Pi Linux, though?